# TMapView not showing the current location at the beginning

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, android-11, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm trying to create an application where the user clicks on a button and a TMapView appears. I just want that the current location of the user to appear to the map at the beginning and not the zero location. This only happens when he presses the device's back button and then the second time it goes to the current location. I don't quite understand why this happens.
Here's the code:

```
procedure TForm2.SetLocation();
var
  LManager : TSensorManager;
  LSensors : TSensorArray;
  LSensor  : TCustomSensor;
  LLocationSensor: TCustomLocationSensor;
begin

  LManager := TSensorManager.Current;
  LManager.Activate;

  LSensors  := LManager.GetSensorsByCategory(TSensorCategory.Location);
  for LSensor in LSensors do
    begin
      LLocationSensor:=LSensor as TCustomLocationSensor;
      LLocationSensor.Start;
      MapView1.Location := TMapCoordinate.Create(LLocationSensor.Latitude,LLocationSensor.Longitude);
    end;
end;
```

Assuming this function is called the first time the map is render.

Comment: Just a guess - maybe the location sensor needs a few seconds time to find out the location. And why do you use `TCustomLocationSensor` and not `TLocationSensor`?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Your guess is correct, I just put the sensor to start at the beginning of the application and not at the beginning of the mapview form, and it worked. As for not using TLocationSensor, this component doesn't have latitude and longitude fields, so I don't know how to make it convert to mapview location. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `OnLocationChanged` event for retrieving your device position. It will fire as soon as location is retrieved. The time for location to be successfully retrieved for the first time is heavily affected by the signal strength. And yes before the event fires for the first time you could do what every other mapping application does and that is show a message on top of the map stating something like `Retrieving current location`

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes, I did it now and it's much better. Thanks. You can post it as a answer and I will accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of `OnLocationChanged` event for retrieving your device position as it will fire as soon as location is retrieved.

Of course time to successfully retrieve initial location is heavily affected by the signal strength.

It is a good practice to notify the user when you are still in the process of retrieving current location.

NOTE: Since `OnLocationChanged` fires every time the location of the device is changed you might want to add yourself some control variable with which you will control whether you want to update location only once or constantly keep tracking the device movement.